# How to import a few excel files as data frames, change the date to the correct format and then pull back the latest date in each file

Tags: python, pandas

I have started trying to learn python to make various tasks within my job easier. I got as far as being able to read an excel file into pandas, but I want to be able to read in about 6 or so files that I have to refresh at regular intervals, have it scan the date column and then nicely and tidily tell me the latest date from each file. This is the code I have so far but I keep getting various errors around date. My date format in the file is '17/07/2021 13:53', although I can see that there are a few that are like '01/06/2022  10:48:02'. I really only want to extract the date and find out the latest date present in these files so I can know how up to date they are.

```
pip.main(["install", "openpyxl","Jinja2"])

import re


import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime

def date_convert(date_to_convert):
    return datetime.strptime(date_to_convert,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    #return datetime.strptime(date_to_convert,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
    #neither one works????

  



df_File1 = pd.read_excel (r'File1Location.xlsx')


df_File2 = pd.read_excel (r'File2Location.xlsx')



df_File1['Date String'] = df_File1['Date Created'].astype("string")
df_File1['Date'] = df_File1d['Date String'].apply(date_convert)





print ("File 1","\n",df_File1['Date Created'].max())
```

I would like to read in about 5 or so of these files and have a nice tidy output that is like

-File 1 : Latest Date: 27/04/2022

-File 2 : Latest Date : 24/04/2022

etc and so on and so forth.

Comment: You could put your code in a loop, looping over all the filenames. Do you have a predetermined set of known names or do you want to read all the files in a folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_path = 'the path of your folder goes here'
filenames = os.listdir(folder_path)

# Or, if you want only to open some files, uncomment next line:
# filenames = [r'File1Location.xlsx', r'File2Location.xlsx', r'File3Location.xlsx', r'File4Location.xlsx']

def print_date(filename):

    df_File = pd.read_excel(filename)

    df_File['Date'] = df_File['Date Created'].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)


    print(filename , ": ", df_File['Date Created'].max().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'), "\n")

for filename in filenames:
    print_date(filename)
```